# XMLRPC problems calling wordpress functions - damaging server?

Tags: php, wordpress, xml-rpc

I have been using methods outlined in http://kovshenin.com/2010/custom-xml-rpc-methods-in-wordpress/ to make custom XMLRPC functions. Everything was going fine up until recently, with many functions implemented successfully.

In particular, I had one function that used get_users() which I could not get working (I kept getting null returned in my responses). However, I noticed that all my other, originally working methods were behaving in the same way. I had not edited or changed them in any way. Commenting out the new function still caused problems in my old functions.

After a while, I got pretty angry, downloaded a fresh installation of wordpress, and copied my old functions and commented out new functions into the clean xmlrpc.php file. I uploaded that to the server, and everything started magically working again.

However, I had another crack at my new function, and seemed to break it in the exact same way again. My solution to use the fresh xmlrpc.php file does not seem to be working either.

Here is the code I believe to be problematic (it is hard to tell, as I tried many different ways to write the same function, believing it was my code being wrong rather than all the methods causing errors, even if they were coded right). All my other functions up until this point had been based around using WP_Query() in different ways.

```
$blogusers = get_users();
foreach ($blogusers as $bloguser) {
    $user = get_userdata($bloguser->ID);
            //put various things into arrays etc  
    }
```

So if any advice could be given to

1) restore my original methods to working order
2) allow me to return an array with information from each user of the blog

That would be fantastic

Comment: Are you sure, your script runs completly? This sounds like memory_limit problem and the script just aborts because of insufficence memory. You could TRY to raise your memory `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M')` if then it works, you have to think about the consequences. setting the memory_limit so high is no good idea (if your server doesn't have really, really much RAM)

Comment: I doubt it is a memory problem. There are only a handful of users and posts etc on my Wordpress website. I'll still try however and see what happens.